# iOS change document picker status bar color not change

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors, statusbar, tint

My init ViewController will show status bar tint color with white color.

I need click the AlertertAction, presentViewController my UIDocumentPickerViewController status bar tint color will changed the the black color.

```
 ...
   cloudAction = [UIAlertAction
               actionWithTitle:@"from cloud"
               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
               {
                 [UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                     [self presentViewController:cloudPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
                }];
 ...
```

And My viewwillappear method set

```
 -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
          [super viewWillAppear:animated];

              [UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

      }
```

it is very strange. When I click the alert, show my cloud picker(UIDocumentPickerViewController) , the stats tint color still whiteColor(on UIDocumentPickerViewController), then click the picker cancel, my view controller changed the black color, not the white color.

Have anyone known how to change the color when I click the alert action , the pick stats bar tint color changed(changed to black color), and dismiss picker , my view controller still white color at status bar tint color.

thank you very much.

Comment: When you hit `cancel` does you `viewWillAppear` method is being called?

Comment: yes , view will appear method is called. And it very strange, I set "[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];" black color, show the cloudPicker status bar tint color still white color, not black color immediately.

Comment: please try `barTintColor` instead of `tintColor` and see what is the behaviour?

Comment: [UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor]; [self presentViewController:cloudPicker animated:YES completion:nil];  The UIDocumentPickerViewController not changed color.

Comment: Init viewcontroller changed white color, But show the document picker view controller not change black color, still white color.

Comment: Ok good, so half of your problem is solved, right? can you show the complete code for UIDocumentPickerViewController? please add the image what you want and what you are getting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154094/discussion-between-dickfala-and-3stud1ant3).

Comment: The author of the question confuses iOS status bar (that displays time and battery) with view controllers's navigation bar.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried changing UINavigationBar's titleTextAttributes?

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]
```